# What is the relationship of .lib and .obj to each other and my project in c++?

Tags: c++, static-libraries

How do .lib and .obj files relate to each other?  What is their purpose?  Is a .lib just a collection of .obj files?  If so are the .obj's then stored inside the .lib making the .obj's unnecessary?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Typically, the `.obj` files refer to *object files*. This is a source file in its compiled form. For example, a `main.cpp` and `foo.cpp` would produce `main.obj` and `foo.obj`.

It is then the linkers job to link them together, so that `main.obj` can reach functions defined in `foo.obj` and vice-versa. The linker will output your binary file, which is the `.lib` (or `.a`, or `.exe`, or .dll``, etc).

So in a loose sense, yes, the binary output (`.lib` in your case) is the collection of linked `.obj` files. Once you are finished compiling, and want to use the library, you only need other programs to link with the `.lib`. The `.obj` are what's considered intermediate files, and are not needed after linking is completed.

Answer (score 2):

This depends.  If the .lib file is a static library, then it is more or less just a collection of .obj files.  If you are making or using a DLL, then the .lib file is just an import library, with information about which symbols are available in the relevant DLL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a .lib file is merely a collection of .obj files.  Nothing was done with the content of the .obj files, the best analogy is a .zip archive.  Yes, you can delete the .obj files after creating the .lib since the .lib contains a verbatim copy of the .obj files.

Beware that if you use a .lib to distribute your product then you'll typically have to create 4 of them.  Debug vs Release build and the two flavors of CRT (/MT vs /MD).